# What is a dramatic word for: very capable and revolutionary

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am searching for a word to describe people who are very competent to the extent that an entire nation can depend on them.

> I understood that my country needs ____ economists just like a human needs oxygen.

I want to imply that these types of economists are **highly needed** because they can take an entire country into **progress**, and because they are 
 **extremely capable** and **skilled**. Also, I want to use a more sophisticated, literary word that would add artfulness to my writing. Any suggestions?

Also, I know that some people will strongly object it, but I will try, anyways. Can anyone suggest me a better analogy for the second part of my sentence (like...oxygen)?

Comment: Visionary? Genius? Heroic? // Woman needs man like a fish needs a bicycle?

Comment: @Cerberus thank you for your suggestions. But regarding the second part, I need quite the contrary. A human, unlike a fish lacking any reasonable need of a bicycle, will die without oxygen. I want to highlight indispensability of good economists, not their inessentiality.

Comment: As an aside, is 'artfulness' the best quality to aspire to with your writing? http://www.dictionary.com/browse/artfulness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[Transformative](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/transformative)**: causing a major change to something..., especially in a way that makes it ... better

A **[transformative](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/transformative)** economist would be one who precipitates a major change in how things are done.  That would likely (though not necessarily) require creativity, in order to see new ways to do things.  It would probably entail being very capable. It is usually used in a positive light.

For your simile, I would look for something that suggests that the economist recognizes and develops some hidden truth.   A *human needs oxygen* to keep on going the way things have always been, but *a seed needs water* in order to grow into something new.

> I understood that my country needs transformative economists just like a seed needs water.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***charismatic*** or ***pragmatic*** here.

> [Charismatic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charisma) : exercising a compelling charm which inspires devotion in others

or

> [Pragmatic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pragmatic) : dealing with things sensibly and realistically in a way that is based on practical rather than theoretical considerations.

As far as as the second part is concerned, I would have framed the sentence something like this:

I understood that my country needed ***pragmatic/charismatic*** economists just like ***breath for soul*** or ***coal for fire***.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you assess words’ drama (dramaticness? dramaticality?)
and/or artfulness,
and this might not convey the leadership qualities you seem to want,
but a somewhat sophisticated, literary word
that could be used to mean  extremely capable and skilled is ***sage***:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sage)
>
> 1. wise through reflection and experience
>
>    proceeding from or characterized by wisdom, prudence, and good judgment
>
>    - *sage* advice
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/sage)
>
>   Having, showing, or indicating profound wisdom.
>   *‘they nodded in agreement with these sage remarks’*
>
> [American Heritage
>   Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sage)
>
> 1. Having or exhibiting wisdom and calm judgment.
>
>    Proceeding from or marked by wisdom and calm judgment: sage advice.
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sage)
>
>   **Sage**
>   means wise and knowledgeable,
>     especially as the result of a lot of experience.
>   *He was famous for his sage advice to younger painters.*